# Return value syntax overloading const and not const function

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

I have a problem providing the correct overloading for const and not const getter functions with the new return value syntax.

In my class `PhysicalNode` I have defined a getter function with the new return value syntax. This is needed as the return type of the getter depends on the type of the member.

```
class PhysicalNode {
private:      
   solver::EnergySolver energySolver_;  ///< The energy solver of this node
   //solver::EnergyMomentumSolver energySolver_
public:
   auto getEnergySolver()-> typename 
        std::add_lvalue_reference<decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)>::type;
}
```

However I want now to also provide this method as const.

Normally I would use function overloading to define my const and not const getter function like that.

```
class PhysicalNode {
private:      
   solver::EnergySolver energySolver_;  
public:
   const solver::EnergySolver& getEnergySolver() const;
   solver::EnergySolver& getEnergySolver();
}
```

I have tried the following function declaration but it does not work:

```
   const auto getEnergySolver() const-> typename
      std::add_lvalue_reference<decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)>::type;
```

The compile error is:

```
PhysicalNode.cpp:72: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
'std::__add_lvalue_reference_helper<LbmLib::solver::EnergySolver, true, 
false>::type {aka LbmLib::solver::EnergySolver&}' from expression of type 
'const LbmLib::solver::EnergySolver'
```

How do I need to define the function declaration to define this function as constant.

Comment: Why are you using `typename`? Is `PhysicalNode` a class template?

Comment: Because I did not get decltype working. But because of your answer I know now how to avoid that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really really want to use this notation and the standard type traits, you should write your `const` overload this way:

```
auto getEnergySolver() const ->
    std::add_lvalue_reference<
        std::add_const<decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)>::type
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        >::type;
```

Otherwise you would be returning a reference to non-`const`, which is clearly wrong considering your member function is `const`-qualified.

Notice, however, that type traits are not really needed here (if `EnergySolver` is just a regular type and not a reference type alias):

```
 auto getEnergySolver()-> decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)&;
 auto getEnergySolver() const -> decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_) const&;
```

But even `decltype` is unnecessary. If your real program is not more complicated than the example you are showing, this is enough:

```
auto getEnergySolver()-> solver::EnergySolver&;
auto getEnergySolver() const -> solver::EnergySolver const&;
```

Comment: What is the benefit of declaring getters this way? seems overly complex

Comment: @paulm: There is no benefit in this concrete situation, I guess the OP just wanted to try out this new syntax

Answer (score 0):

`decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)` is plain `EnergySolver`, not `const EnergySolver` even though the method is `const`, since the expression doesn't use `this`, which is what that `const` qualifier really affects.  And you're not allowed to use `decltype(this->energySolver_)` in this context since `PhysicalNode` is not yet complete.

You'll have to do something like `-> const decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)&;` or `-> std::add_lvalue_reference<std::add_const<decltype(PhysicalNode::energySolver_)>::type>::type;` or something in between.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why the "traditional" method is not good for your purposes.

The machination with decltype and add/remove trickery is to cover ground for templates that want to be overly generic. Where you must deal with unknown types and ones you have no control over.

For the usual situations it is way clearer to just add a few typedefs and use those directly.

For your attempt, IMO you use it incorrectly, either try const auto& in front, or auto in front and assemble the type all the way after the ->, combininge remove_reference, then add_const then add_lvalue_reference, it may work, though would make head spin.